# Change git remote url to include username without losing branch tracking info

Tags: git, github, ssh

Say I have this:

```
origin  git@github.com:org/repo.git (fetch)
```

I want to add my username to the url, for the purposes of auth via ssh, so I want to change it to this:

```
origin  git@github.com-the1mills:org/repo.git (fetch)
```

however, when I do that, I lose tracking info for my current branch and probably all my branches.

Is there a way to modify the remote url without losing tracking info?

Comment: When you do that how exactly? What command are you running? `git remote rm origin` and `git remote add origin ...`?

Comment: yeah i did rm/add once, and that was a mistake lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`git remote set-url`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) to change just the URL of a remote.

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com-the1mills:org/repo.git
```

Comment: just as easy to go into .git/config and manually modify, as I found out

Comment: Helped a lot! This is the best way to change repo address. Thanks!